# Setting Options 66 and 67 for ISC DHCP Server

Tags: 14.04, bootloader, dhcp, lan, cisco

How to set Option 66 and Option 67 for DHCP in [isc-dhcp-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server)?

- 066 Boot Server Host Name
- 067 Bootfile Name

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I think I find answer myself, see edited question.

Comment: Yes, I did it..

Answer (score 2):

I should edit dhcpd.conf file

```
nano -w /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

and to add the following entries for activating the option 66 and 67.

```
#option 66
option tftp-server-name "w.x.y.z";

#option 67
option bootfile-name "test.cfg";
```

Then to restart the DHCP Server.

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Comment: man dhcp-options

     option tftp-server-name text;

       This option is used to identify a TFTP server and, if sup-
       ported  by  the client, should have the same effect as the
       server-name declaration.   BOOTP clients are  unlikely  to
       support  this  option.  Some DHCP clients will support it,
       and others actually require it.

Answer (score 0):

man dhcpd.conf

```
   next-server server-name;

   The next-server statement is  used  to  specify  the  host
   address  of  the  server  from which the initial boot file
   (specified in the filename statement)  is  to  be  loaded.
   Server-name  should  be  a  numeric IP address or a domain
   name.
```